# Автоматическое обновление Report view в MS Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, settings

Как сделать так, чтобы репорт обновлялся через определенный промежуток времени?

Пробовал так,

```
<report>
<autorefresh>15</autorefresh>

<body>
...
</body>
</report>
```

Ругается при исполнении так:

- *`Deserialization failed: The report definition element 'Report' contains more than one child element of type 'AutoRefresh' at line
  1327, position 3. Line 1327, position 3.`*

Может, есть какая-то галочка в настройках?

Answer (score 1):

нужно клиннуть в дизайнере на желтую облать во круг репорта, и в пропитис будет пункт Autorefresh ( Указывать в секундах )